# When to use os.Exit() and panic()?

Tags: go, exit

Could someone explain the key differences between `os.Exit()` and `panic()` and how they are used in practice in Go?

Comment: Just a comment that will hopefully help in future Go code reading: In a lot of example code, `panic` is used to exit on error, purely due to the fact that it's easy to understand, and eliminates importing any other packages. This *doesn't mean it's good, or idiomatic practice!*. It's just a space saving device for example code. IRL reserve `panic` for *very* special situations.

Comment: Hm..good) especially "IRL" abbreviation - it's new for me :) Could you explain how panic eliminates package importing?

Comment: `panic` is a builtin. It's recommended (depending on circumstance) to use something like `os.Exit`, `log.Fatal` etc., which will return an error code to the OS (always recommended if possible). These all involve importing a package, and thus "clutter up" example code. Example code should always only be taken to demonstrate a solution to a specific problem. There may be other problems with the code, which make the code more complex if properly demonstrated, and therefore detract from the explanation of the answer given. YMMV.

Comment: Ok, got it!) Big thanks) I see there is yet another abbreviation for my vocabulary :)

Comment: NP, happy to help, and to increase your acronymic lexicon :-)

Comment: can't upvote @Intermernet 's comment enough! There is no production code case where a panic (or even os.Exit would ever be needed). A memory allocation failure is the only scenario for a panic. And os.Exit is just lazy - wait for your go-routines to complete!

Answer (score 129, accepted):

First of all, whenever you have a "how it is used in practice" question, a good way to start is to [search](http://golang.org/search?q=os.Exit) the Go source code (or any big enough Go code base, really), and the [package docs](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit) for answers.

Now, `os.Exit` and `panic` are quite different. [`panic`](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#panic) is used when the program, or its part, has reached an unrecoverable state.

> When `panic` is called, including implicitly for run-time errors such as indexing a slice out of bounds or failing a type assertion, it immediately stops execution of the current function and begins unwinding the stack of the goroutine, running any deferred functions along the way. If that unwinding reaches the top of the goroutine's stack, the program dies.

`os.Exit` is used when you need to abort the program *immediately,* with no possibility of recovery or running a deferred clean-up statement, and also return an error code (that other programs can use to report what happened). This is useful in tests, when you already know that after this one test fails, the other will fail as well, so you might as well just exit now. This can also be used when your program has done everything it needed to do, and now just needs to exit, i.e. after printing a help message.

Most of the time you won't use `panic` (you should return an `error` instead), and you almost never need `os.Exit` outside of some cases in tests and for quick program termination.

Comment: "This is useful in tests, when you already know that after this one test fails, the other will fail as well…" This smells of a testing anti-pattern of dependent tests. In a well-written test suite, each test is independent; the outcome of any given test should never determine the outcome of any other test.

Comment: @gotgenes Not necessarily. If I have a test that a certain function returns a non-nil struct, and that test fails, then I can expect that all the tests that examine the values of the struct are going to fail, too. It's the code that's dependent, not the tests. (That said, I wouldn't use `exit` in that case, I'd just expect a big stack of failed assertions.)

Answer (score 114):

First of all, `os.Exit()` can be used to exit the program normally without an error, and panic not, so that's one key distinction. Another is that panic somewhere can be caught and ignored or logged using `recover`.

But if we're talking about an erroneous exit code, let's say:

Use `panic` when something goes horribly wrong, probably a programmer error that should have been caught before going to production. This is why it prints the stack.

Use `os.Exit(errorCode)` or something like that if you want to:

1. control the exit code of the program for scripting purposes.
2. want an orderly exit on an error that is expected (e.g user input error).

So basically panic is for you, a bad exit code is for your user.

Comment: "So basically panic is for you, a bad exit code is for your user." <- Awesome tip

Comment: Could we say that panic() is somehow related to the usual assert() call in plain C? Well.. I know I always remove asserting call before pushing to production, I only enable them when testing a new feature. What I am saying is that most of time I use assert() to verify invariants that I guess must hold true in my code. Do you see the same usage for panic() ? :-)

Comment: Shouldn't we mention the key difference that panic generates a stack trace and os.Exit() does not?

Answer (score 17):

The key differences are:

1. `os.Exit` skips the execution of deferred function.
2. With `os.Exit`, you can specify the exit code.
3. `panic` is terminating while `os.Exit` is not. (Seems other answers do not mention this.)

If you need to execute the deferred function, you have no choice but `panic`. (On the other hand, if you want to skip execution of deferred function, use `os.Exit`.)

If a non-void function is defined in such a way:

1. the function contains a lot of branches
2. all branches are terminated with `return` or `panic`

Then you cannot replace `panic` with `os.Exit` otherwise the compiler will refuse to compile the program, saying "missing return at end of function". (Go is very dumb here, even `log.Panic` does not terminate a function.)

Under other conditions:

1. Use `panic` when something really wired happens, e.g. programming logic error.
2. Use `os.Exit` when you want an immediate exit, with specified exit code.